# Sending dictionary from a VC to another VC through Custom delegtes

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have a class in which response from server is coming as responseDictionary.I want to use this responseDictionary in another VC but not able to send the dictionary through delegates.Kindly explain with code  in objective c that how this can be achieved.

Comment: Are you using segues for VC to VC transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample project, it is simply for demo, u can refer it

first we will create a class names `WebService` it will request the data, and as a response it will get a dictionary, and also it defines a delegate to notify that data is received and sent to the VC (in your case)

in `WebService.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol WebServiceDelegate;
@interface WebService : NSObject
{

}
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<WebServiceDelegate>webServiceDelegate;

- (void)webserviceRequestData; //initiates the data request
@end


@protocol WebServiceDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)webService:(WebService *)aWebService didReceievResponseData:(NSDictionary *)dataDictionary;
@end
```

in `WebService.m`

```
#import "WebService.h"

@implementation WebService

- (instancetype)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if(self)
   {

   }
   return self;
}

- (void)webserviceRequestData
{
   sleep(5); //for demo 
   [self makeWebserviceToGetSomeData];
}

- (void)makeWebserviceToGetSomeData
{
   NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Data_1",@"Key_1",@"Data_2",@"Key_2",@"Data_3",@"Key_3", nil];
  [self receievedSomeData:data];
}

 //finally data is received as dictionary and send it to VC
- (void)receievedSomeData:(NSDictionary *)dataDictionary
{
    if([self.webServiceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webService:didReceievResponseData:)])
        [self.webServiceDelegate webService:self didReceievResponseData:dataDictionary];
}

@end
```

and in the view controller class `ViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WebService.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<WebServiceDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, strong) WebService *myWebService; 
@end
```

and in `ViewController.m`

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   _myWebService = [[WebService alloc] init];
   _myWebService.webServiceDelegate = self; //this is call back to this class
 }

 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   [_myWebService webserviceRequestData];
 }

 - (void)webService:(WebService *)aWebService didReceievResponseData:(NSDictionary *)dataDictionary
{
   NSLog(@"web data:%@",dataDictionary.description);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

after 5 seconds we made to call the method `makeWebserviceToGetSomeData` and it will send the call the another method `receievedSomeData:` method in this we are  checking weather caller implemented the method or not to avoid crash(unrecognised selector sent to object), and we are passing the data (dictionary) to view controller

and also u can call web service from any class (any viewcontroller) and set it as a delegate

Comment: Hi! I have tried it...Just have a small doubt how can a call the method - (void)webService:(WebService *)aWebService didReceievResponseData:(NSDictionary *)dataDictionary on a button click

Comment: The button is on ViewController and i want this function to work on the click of this button

Comment: the method ` - (void)webService:(WebService *)aWebService didReceievResponseData:(NSDictionary *)dataDictionary ` is called by the web service to notify the data is received. if u want to send that data to next view controller u can use another delegate  or notification or assign he dictionary to second view controller while initialising